# JUnit Testing Adding Complex Numbers

Tags: java, junit, complex-numbers

I am trying pass my j unit test for my code for adding complex numbers together but i keep getting a failure. I am unsure as to why that is.

Add code

```
// Adds one Complex Number with another
    public ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber a) {
        MyDouble realNum = this.real.add(a.real);
        MyDouble imagNum = this.imag.add(a.imag);
        return new ComplexNumber(realNum, imagNum);

    }
```

The .add is from another class, MyDouble, in which it adds two doubles together.

JUnit Code

```
@Test
    public void testAdd() {
        MyDouble a = new MyDouble(1.5), b = new MyDouble(2.0);
        MyDouble c = new MyDouble(2.5), d = new MyDouble(3.0);

        MyDouble realNum = a.add(c);
        MyDouble imagNum = b.add(d);

        ComplexNumber x = new ComplexNumber(a,b);
        ComplexNumber y = new ComplexNumber(c,d);

        assertTrue(new ComplexNumber(realNum, imagNum) == y.add(x) );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This test does not pass because the comparison is made by reference and not by value:

```
assertTrue(new ComplexNumber(realNum, imagNum) == y.add(x));
```

`new ComplexNumber(args)` creates a new object instance, while `y.add(x)` returns another object instance. The assertion fails, because their references are not same, even though the values wrapped in these objects might be equal.

In Java, the comparison with "==" is very often confusing when one starts to code.

To solve the problem with this test case, you should try

```
assertEquals(new ComplexNumber(realNum, imagNum), y.add(x));
```

Provided that `ComplexNumber` implements the `equals` method (if necessary, please check resources on implementing it, they are legion).